# JQUERY + Apache Cordova

Tags: jquery, apache

tengo un problema con querys y con apache cordova. En principio el servidor me responde con un XML , lo proceso bien y todo. Pero luego hace unas 42.000 querys. Que es el realidad lo que tiene que hacer. Pero esto mismo hace que la tablet se pille. Hay alguna manera de hacer que esas querys no peten la tablet?

Un saludo.

Comment: 42K querys??? Lógico que se te bloquee, aporta mas información sobre que tipo de query, porque de esas querys y mas datos para que sea mas fácil ayudarte.

Comment: Son 42.000 inserts a una base de datos sqlite.

Answer (score 0):

La solución mas sencilla es que realices todo ese proceso de inserción en otro hilo de ejecución, porque lo mas seguro es que estés bloqueando el hilo principal hasta que se terminen las 42.000 insercciones.

Lamentablemente no tengo mucho conocimiento de Apache Cordova y no te puedo poner un ejemplo :(

Pero en la documentación de Cordova aparece una sección de [Threading](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/es/latest/guide/platforms/android/plugin.html#threading) que es lo que necesitas.